# Can I calculate stock value with Williams%R if I know the last set?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

I've got a random stock. Yesterday the value was $76.25, where as the Williams %R was -72.72.

Is it possible by only knowing this, to calculate the value if the Williams %R rises to -20?

Answer (score 1):

William %R is a momentum indicator used for measuring overbought and oversold levels, it is not used to predict the price of a stock. In fact, William %R, like all momentum indicators, is a lagging indicator - meaning the indicator level changes as the price of the stock changes.

It ranges from 0 to -100. Usually when a reading is less than -80 the stock can be considered to be oversold, and when the reading is above -20 the stock can be considered overbought. When viewed together with the price chart, this can help provide a trader with entry and exit points into and out of a trade.